# In android sdk26 replacement of fragment after clearing backstack not properly working.What is the solution?

Tags: android, android-fragments

```
if (id == R.id.profile) {
    Profile fr = new Profile();
    FragmentTransaction fm = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    clearBackStack();
    fm.replace(R.id.content_frame,fr);
    fm.addToBackStack("Profile");
    fm.commit();
}
```

this code first gives the profile fragment. When again pressing this code gives home page. But it is properly working in SDK 23

Comment: show `clearBackStack();`

Comment: private void clearBackStack() {

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            Log.e("cleared","backstack");
            FragmentManager.BackStackEntry first = manager.getBackStackEntryAt(0);
            manager.popBackStack(first.getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Change your clear backstack like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   clearBackStack();
}


private void clearBackStack() {
     FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
     if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        Fragment fragment=manager.findFragmentById(R.id.YOUR_FRAME_LAYOUT);
        if(fragment!=null && fragment.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase(YOUR_FRAGMENT.class.getSimpleName())){
            manager.popBackStackImmediate();
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Also dont clear backstack while adding fragments.Only when pressing back button clear the stack by popping fragments.Remove `clearBackStack()` from the code while adding fragments.

Comment: This code is working.But if I press the same id for 3 times, it will add 3 same fragments. So to go for the home page i have to press backbutton 3 times.That is my actual issue

Comment: then try calling that method while loading fragments also